# MFC how to dock fill control?

Tags: c++, mfc

How do I force listctrl into tabctrl and from tabctrl into dialog?

Also is there a way to align the checkbox to the center of first column or only justify text to the center?

[image]

Comment: Will probably be easier to get an answer if you provide some of the code that got this dialog.

Comment: Hi @Jeffrey, from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27914005/how-to-make-the-header-checkbox-of-the-listcontrol-column-to-be-aligned-perfectl  you can do it.

Comment: Resize the tab control from its parent's [CWnd::OnSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#onsize) implementation. From the `CTabCtrl`'s `OnSize` member you can calculate the display are size based on the window size ([CTabCtrl::AdjustRect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctabctrl-class#adjustrect)). Once that is done you can resize the `CListCtrl` to fill the entire display area of the tab control.

Comment: Hi @IInspectable,  i created an added column to adjust order numbers and based on your answer. my problem solved. Many thanks!

Comment: Use `CMFCTabCtrl` and you will avoid a lot of manual show/hide controls logic. And if you declare that list control as the window of the respective tab (may be with `CMFCTabCtrl::AddTab`), you will have the resize behaviour automatically done for you.

Comment: Hi, i definitely want to try it. however when including CMFCTabCtrl header file i got ambiguous symbol bytes error. i got stuck there and came back to this control :(.